# Inserting the custom Composable inside Markdown Text in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

So I need to insert the audio player which is composable inside markdown text, I'll give an example in form of an image how I expect it to look like. Also, [this](https://www.hellsoft.se/rendering-markdown-with-jetpack-compose/) is the code and the approach that I've followed in my implementation. In the last code snippet, you can find this piece of code, but this is my version:

```
    inlineContent = mapOf(URL to InlineTextContent(
    
    Placeholder(INLINE_TEXT_WIDTH, INLINE_TEXT_HEIGHT,PlaceholderVerticalAlign.Center)) {
    
    AudioPlayer(it, alignment = Alignment.Center)
    
    } ),
```

I've tried to put my Composable instead of CoilImage and it didn't turn out well for me. Because the audio player has almost full width and the height is about 190.sp and the result I get is that the text is covered by the audio player.

The result I want is when I send the markdown content and if inside it is some .mp3 to show my custom(audio player) composable then and below that the rest of the text.

So, I am looking for help to figure it out and find a way to make this work.